# Where does session data store in redmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I was trying to find the location of session values store in redmine. When a user is login, where does its information goes that has been stored in session.

Answer (score 3):

Redmine stores session data in a cookie (as is the default in Rails apps in general). As such, there is no actual session data stored on the server.

The session data in the cookies are cryptographically signed in a way that actual end users can not change them. However, the information is visible to them which means that you shouldn't store sensitive (or large amounts of) data in there.

Coincidentally, this is also why you need to create the session secret when you first install Redmine. It is used to sign the cookie and to ensure that the data wasn't tampered with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand the question but if you want to access the session variable you can do:

```
session[:foo]
```